# Zonal statistics as a table error code 010429

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, error-010429

[image]

I am trying to extract majority land-use type from a land-use raster (TIFF, unsigned integer, 30X30 m cell size) into a multipart polygon feature class (which contains ~1300 200-m radium circular polygons) using "zonal statistics tool" of ArcGIS 10.3.1.  My goal is to know the major land-use type in each of my circular polygons.

The land-use raster's extent is the conterminous US. I set up the geoprocessing environment correctly (processing extent, ell size), yet I keep getting the following sets of error messages:

[image: error message].

The detailed error messages are also posted here. I think the issue starts with the first error- there's nothing wrong with the raster dataset and I am not memory full either....

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: How many values are present in the land use raster? I would suspect that the land use isn't the problem, it sounds like you have more than 100000 FID values.. or that you have multiple overlapping buffers. Is python an option for you?

Comment: Either the input raster is corrupted or you do not have enough computer memory to execute the tool.  Here is the link to the error code. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vq0000000z010429.

Comment: There are 17 values (i.e., 17 land-use types) in the land-use raster. I am not sure what you meant by >100000 FIDs... I am not an expert on phyton, but I can certainly manage basic codes.

Comment: FIDs are the unique IDs of each row. Where you have overlapping polygons, it is my understanding, that the polygons are *planarized* so that there are no overlaps, each new polygon created gets a new FID. What did you get when you clicked on the error links? I would recommend repairing the polygon feature class http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003v000000, just in case there's a bad geometry or two, a single non-simple or incorrect ring orientation can prevent processes from running properly.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - I ran my polygon feature class through "repair geometry" tool. There are 1318 FIDs and these polygons have some overlap. The issue still persists. The error all the error messages are pasted on the top. But, none of these makes sense.

Comment: Try selecting just one polygon in ArcMap and see if that works, if it does it shouldn't be too hard to script it to iteratively execute for each input polygon, what statistic type are you after in landuse?

Comment: yeah, that actually worked..!!!! in a matter of 1-2 secs. previously, it takes a few mins before the tool failed. I am using majority as the stat type since I am interested in the major land use type inside my circular polygons. I think I am gonna make a model builder with iterators-- I can manage that. Thank you @MichaelStimson...

Comment: @MichaelStimson-- so the issue was the greater number of polygons??? both the raster and the overall geometry of the feature class seemed not the issue...

Comment: I'd say it's the overlap of the polygons generating thousands of sliver polygons when planarized. When you get your script working please answer your own question with screen shots of your model for the benefit of future users with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [image: model builder] for my original post. Since my feature class layer generates so many overlapping polygons so Zonal stats as a table did not work. So, I broke up my original multi-polygon feature class into separate shapefiles and then extracted LU per each polygon based on Zontal Stats and append all tables generated into a single table- which is what I needed. Thanks @MichaelStimson for the initial suggestions.